# How to add and save sections/headers dynamically in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Right now I have a list of todo items, saved with CoreData.  I am using SwiftUI.  This is only one Core Data entity.

[image]

How would I be able to add sections/headers to my list dynamically and then save where they are located for the next launch?  What would I use to save the sections/headers?
Please note that the user will be able to make as many sections/headers as they wish and drag them around.

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Your question is quite vague and there are many possibilities. It all depends on your persistence setup but saving a "custom Index" for the sections/headers and having `onMove` activated is probably something close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  Right now, my persistence setup is only saving todo items into a CoreData stack.  Any ideas on how I would insert a section/header to a list?

Comment: There are [many questions in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CoreData+swiftui+sections) on the subject. Like I said there are many options dynamic grouping, `NSFetchedResultsController`, filtering, having "Section/Category objects", etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you have your data fetched by categories or state you could do something like the following:

```
struct Item {
    let title: String
    ...
}

struct Category {
    let title: String
    let items: [Item]
    ...
}

class ViewModel {
    var categories: [Category]
    ...
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.categories) { category in
                Section(header: header(for: category.title)) {
                    ForEach(category.items) { item in
                        RowView(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    func header(for title: String) -> some View {
        Text(title) // You can change this as per you design
    }
}
```

Comment: ok.  But how would the position of where the section was located be preserved and saved after the user moves the section around?

Comment: Dragging the section would change something line the data source index that would be used to sort the data array. Makes sense?